# Creating a new child reference in a newly created document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have the following two schema's:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
name:{type:String},
email:{type:email},
profile:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Profile"}
})
```

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
user:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"},
})
```

I am using the following to upsert/update documents:

```
User.updateMany(
{email:email},
{$set:{email: "tom@hp.com", name:"Tom Riddle"}},
{$upsert:true})
```

But I would like to also create profile for the user if they're being upserted. What is the most optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a mongoose's post hook after saving.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post

```
UserSchema.post("save", async (doc) => {
  // Create user profile depending on user
  const { account_type, profile = null, _id } = doc;

  if (!profile)
    switch (account_type) {
      case "user": {
        const profile = await new UserProfile({
          user: _id,
        });

        doc.profile = profile._id;
        const updated = await doc.save();
        console.log(updated);
 
        break;
      }
    }
});
```